# CLI testing with Jasmine / PhantomJS

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, yeoman

Running `yeoman server:test` opens Jasmine in my browser and says that my test has passed. Now I want to try the same, but without a browser - using PhantomJS on the CLI. Unfortunately, running `yeoman test` only throws a:

```
Running "jasmine:all" (jasmine) task
Running specs for index.html
>> 0 assertions passed in 0 specs (0ms)
```

Why doesn't it find any tests, even though everything is included in my `test/index.html` and works pretty well using `yeoman server:test`?

I used `yeoman init jasmine:app --force` over my project and adjusted the `Gruntfile.js` as described [here](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/437). It looks like that:

```
...
// headless testing through PhantomJS
jasmine: {
    all: ["test/**/*.html"]
},
...
// Alias the `test` task to run the `jasmine` task instead
grunt.registerTask("test", "jasmine");
...
```

Note: My tests are written in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found out that PhantomJS is not able to find the files at the same location as ´yeoman server´ or `yeoman server:test` does.

I precised my question in another thread: [Running tests in both headless and browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086501/running-tests-in-both-headless-and-browser)