# Running tests in both headless and browser

Tags: yeoman

I'd like to run my tests in PhantomJS using `yeoman test` as well as in browser using `yeoman server:test`. The problem though is that PhantomJS doesn't find my includes in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="scripts/view/customer_view.js"></script>
```

...because it looks inside the `test/`-directory. Of course it would work if I tell my coffee-task to duplicate all the files into the `test/`-directory as well. But that seems wrong.

So, is there any way to use:

1. the same include paths for headless and browser?
2. the same files that have already been created in /temp/scripts? (because I use CoffeeScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deeper [on GitHub](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/588), I found out that I have to replace the URI in the `Gruntfile.js`:

```
// headless testing through PhantomJS
// mocha: {
jasmine: {
    // all: ["test/**/*.html"]
    all: ["http://localhost:3501/index.html"]
}
```

**Note**

As of Yeoman *0.9.6* it's also required to modify the grunt task:

```
// Alias the `test` task to run the `jasmine` task instead
// grunt.registerTask("test", "jasmine");
grunt.registerTask("test", "server:phantom jasmine");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to accept your answer! ;-)